# How do I determine the query that sp_cursorfetch is using

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Profiler shows my server is overloaded by lots of calls to sp_cursorfetch, but I want to know which queries are causing all this traffic.

Comment: Looks like SQL2005/2008 can do it this way:
http://dbaspot.com/forums/ms-sqlserver/141465-how-can-i-find-out-what-command-sp_execute-running-without-using-profiler.html

Answer (score 3):

Profiler won't work in this case.

I ran one to test it out, and queried the table I created from it with this:

select CPU, TextData FROM cpu where LoginName = 'db_name_here' order by CPU desc

// Be sure to replace db_name_here

Result I got showed stuff like this:

```
CPU----TextData-----------------------------

0------exec sp_cursorfetch 180150000, 16, 7415, 1
```

*Note: The "-" above are just to format it so it's actually readable on this site.

========

The only answers I found on this are:

- Select statements are the only cause of these cursor fetches, and examining your indexes of most commonly used tables is a good 1st start to resolving the problem
- You maybe able to filter a trace on the SPID of the cursorfetch call to see what it's doing before and after the sp_cursorfetch is ran.
- Only fetch a subset of the total RecordSet you are currently. Say you grab 100 rows now. Only grab 10,because 10 is the most the user can see at any given time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, all of which are helpful.  Unfortunately the queries in question are from a third party application, of which I do not have direct access to view or modify the queries.  If I find a query that is a particuar problem, I can submit a support request to have it reviewed.  I just need to know what the query is, first.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the comment:

```
Thanks for your suggestions, all of which are helpful. Unfortunately the queries in question are from a third party application, of which I do not have direct access to view or modify the queries. If I find a query that is a particuar problem, I can submit a support request to have it reviewed. I just need to know what the query is, first. – Shandy Apr 21 at 8:17
```

You don't need access to the application to try out most of my aforementioned recommendations. Lets go over them:

1. Select statements are the only cause of these cursor fetches, and examining your indexes of most commonly used tables is a good 1st start to resolving the problem

   - This is done on the database server. You need to just run a tuning profile on the database, and to run the SQL Tuning Advisor using the profile generated. This will assist with improving indexes
2. You maybe able to filter a trace on the SPID of the cursorfetch call to see what it's doing before and after the sp_cursorfetch is ran.

   - This is something you do using SQL profiler as well
3. Only fetch a subset of the total RecordSet you are currently. Say you grab 100 rows now. Only grab 10,because 10 is the most the user can see at any given time.

   - This is done at the application level

What SQL server version are you running on? The resolution for this ended up being an upgrade to SQL Server 2008 in my case. I would try this out to see where it goes.

Since you don't have access to the application, getting around cursor use is going to be a problem most likely. If you take a look at http://sqlpractices.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/performance-tuning-sql-server-cursors/ you can see that most alternatives involve editing the application queries ran.

What is the real problem? Why are you profiling the database?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use [profiler](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-an-introduction-to-sql-server-profiler/5054787) for this.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, if you are doing a batch process execution plan might be helpful.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: (sorry - I've corrected the question - I was using profier). A.